# Need to generate a score for a trivia game in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
question with answer    
 {
        question: "Rogue was adopted by whom?",
        answers: [
          "Xavier",
          "Wolverine",
          "Jean Gray",
          "Mystique"
        ],
        correctAnswer: 1
      }

    //// print questions and answers for rogue
    $(".rogue").append(myQuestions[5].question);

    for (i = 0; i < myQuestions[5].answers.length; i++) {
      $('<li><input type="radio" name="rbtnCount" value =' + i + '>' + myQuestions[4].answers[i] + "</li>").appendTo(".rogue")
    }
    $(".rogue").on("change", function () {
      var selected = $('input[name=rbtnCount]:checked').val();
      console.log(selected)
      console.log(myQuestions[5].correctAnswer)
      if (selected == myQuestions[5].correctAnswer) {
        alert("its right!!!")
      } else {
        alert("better luck on nextone!!")
      }
    })

    /// print score based on correct and incorrect
    $(".corr").append(correctAnswer);
      if(correctAnswer)  <--- not certain on my next step here to create the scoring.
```

//// im stuck here, not understanding my next steps here. need to create a score based on the selected correct answer and score for the the incorrect.

Comment: Have you tried creating a variable to count each and adding one to the number each time the answer is right or wrong?

Comment: Hoo... You need to be more specific than *«I'm stuck here»*. What EXACTLY is the issue? What are the error message or misbehaviors you have. --- THEN read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about how to give the community the minimal info to recreate your issue and help. No on can do without it. As it is now, and from my experience here, your question risk to be CLOSED quite fast. Edit it with more details... You have a link below your question, to edit. Add your HTML, CSS and steps to recreate a SPECIFIC issue.

Comment: updated the question. sorry about that